# CLLocationManager + monitoring for CLBeaconRegion

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm trying to make applications, which ranges CLBeaconRegion.

I watched video from WWDC and presenter said, that I should call startMonitoringForRegion and, then user is inside region, startRangingBeaconsInRegion. I tried.

```
if (!_locationManager) {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

CLBeaconRegion *targetRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:UUIDString] identifier:identifier];
targetRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
targetRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
targetRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;

[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:targetRegion];
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

But it's not sending nothing to delegate. Beacons is working.

If I call just

```
[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
```

Applications finds all my beacons around me.

Should I just call second method or I'm incorrect?

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: I had similar problem, which was occurring on just one device out of 3 used for testing. I decided to skip `startMonitoringForRegion` and go straight for `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`. I guess the only consequance is it could lead to a little higher battery usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you are not waiting long enough to get a call to your delegate.  When you are *NOT* ranging, it takes up to 15 minutes to get callbacks to the delegate methods below.  When you are ranging, it takes only 1 second.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

If you wait the 15 minutes, I suspect you will get the callbacks as expected.  The reason it is so much faster when you are ranging is because iOS does constant bluetooth scans when ranging is enabled to look for iBeacons.  When you are not ranging, it slows down these scans to save battery.  See more info in the blog posts below:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html

Comment: Hm... Can I make location manager to do it faster? It's important to me to make it as quick as possible

Comment: Sure, simply start ranging whenever you start monitoring.  When your app is in the foreground, you should csee 1 second detection times.  In the background, you will have to live with the limits of iOS which will slow down scasns to save battery.